# ScrollViewer not to scroll when content does not exceed parent's height

Tags: xaml, scroll, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

In this XAML I can scroll `Contents` grid up and down a bit even though it does not exceed the `ScrollViewer` height.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="Controller" Grid.Row="0">
        <controls:SearchField x:Name="Searcher" />
    </Grid>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer.Content>
            <Grid x:Name="Contents">
                <TextBlock Text="HI" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer.Content>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I guess it is a standard behavior of some kind but I don't like it too much. It it possible to make `ScrollViewer` not to scroll it's contents if they don't exceed `ScrollViewer`'s height?

Comment: What you're describing and showing example of is not expected behavior unless the content genuinely does require scrolling. Do you have `VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Auto"` set?

Comment: @ChrisW. I didn't but adding it does not help.

Comment: @ChrisW. Maybe I was not clear enough, the scollbar itself is not visible but I still can drag content up and down for some small distance and then it returns back in place.

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay attention to the wp-8 Tag, that was my mistake. I imagine it would take a little more creativity then. Let me ask though, does it move only the scrollviewer content? Or does the parent scrollviewer seem to move also?

Comment: @ChrisW. It only moves "Hi" text block.